# Kafka Consumers (in Confluent Cloud) stops consumption after Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am getting the following exception in the Kafka consumer in my AWS ECS service.

```bash
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create Kafka transaction; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: TransactionalId item-availability-view-tx:41e90b10-0690-487b-8a26-9a4dcb295fbditem_availability_view_service_menu_item_changes.MENU_ITEMS_CHANGE_SYNC_FOR_86N.2: Invalid transition attempted from state IN_TRANSACTION to state IN_TRANSACTION
    at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doBegin(KafkaTransactionManager.java:162) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1621) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1596) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1330) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1062) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:970) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: TransactionalId item-availability-view-tx:41e90b10-0690-487b-8a26-9a4dcb295fbditem_availability_view_service_menu_item_changes.MENU_ITEMS_CHANGE_SYNC_FOR_86N.2: Invalid transition attempted from state IN_TRANSACTION to state IN_TRANSACTION
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.transitionTo(TransactionManager.java:1053) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.transitionTo(TransactionManager.java:1046) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.beginTransaction(TransactionManager.java:338) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.beginTransaction(KafkaProducer.java:612) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.beginTransaction(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:795) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer.beginTransaction(TracingProducer.java:69) ~[brave-instrumentation-kafka-clients-5.12.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ProducerFactoryUtils.java:99) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doBegin(KafkaTransactionManager.java:146) ~[spring-kafka-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
```

The consumer is defined as follows.

```java
public interface UpdateSyncConsumer {
  @KafkaListener(
      id = "update_sync_consumer",
      topics = "${app.kafka.topics.UPDATES_TOPIC}",
      containerFactory = "updatesListenerFactory")
  @Transactional
  void handleUpdate(
      ConsumerRecord<String, UpdateAvro> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack);
}
```

And, the consumer is implemented as follows.

```java
@Component
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultUpdateSyncConsumer implements
    UpdateSyncConsumer {

  private final UpdateAvroMapper avroMapper;
  private final UpdateJobScheduler updateJobScheduler;

  @Override
  public void handleUpdate(
      final ConsumerRecord<String, UpdateAvro> consumerRecord,
      final Acknowledgment ack) {
    try {
      log.info(
          "Scheduling Update Sync: payload: {} count:{}",
          consumerRecord.value(),
          consumerRecord.value().getItemIds().size());

      updateJobScheduler.scheduleUpdateSyncAttempt(avroMapper.map(consumerRecord.value()));
      log.info("Scheduled Update Sync: DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("ERROR: Scheduling Update Sync: {}", Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e));
    } finally {
      ack.acknowledge();
      log.info("Acknowledged: {}", consumerRecord.key());
    }
  }
}
```

Consumer configuration is as follows.

```java
@Log4j2
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConsumerConfig extends KafkaBasicConfig {

  private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> basicConfig = getBasicConfig();
    basicConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    basicConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    basicConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
    basicConfig
        .put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    basicConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    basicConfig
        .put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    basicConfig.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS,
        KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    basicConfig.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(basicConfig);
  }

  @Bean(name = "updatesListenerFactory")
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      KafkaTransactionManager<String, Object> ktm) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(6);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(ktm);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(afterRollbackProcessor());
    return factory;
  }

  private DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<String, Object> afterRollbackProcessor() {
    DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<String, Object> processor =
        new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>((rec, exception) -> {
          log.error(
              "!!!!!!!!!!! Following Record keeps failing despite multiple attempts, therefore would be skipped !! : "
                  + rec);
          log.error(exception);
        }, new FixedBackOff(1000L, 2L));
    processor.setCommitRecovered(true);
    processor.setKafkaTemplate(kafkaTemplate);
    processor.setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level.ERROR);
    processor.addNotRetryableException(SerializationException.class);
    return processor;
  }
}
```

The topic is configured with three (03) partitions and the service has two instances in AWS meaning, there are two consumers polling on 3 topics.

The exception mentioned above causes the consumers to stop consumption. Can someone see what's causing this issue?

Comment: You don't need `@Transactional` on the listener method - the container will start the transaction (but that shouldn't be causing the problem). DEBUG logging should help understand why an attempt to call `beginTransaction` is made while we already have  a transaction. It also looks like you are doing some async processing, which is not recommended because the ack will be completed before the work.

Comment: @GaryRussell As far as the async processing is concerned, I am scheduling a job to process the message at a later time due to our very low timeouts for ACK. I'll try to see the DEBUG logs as you have suggested...

Comment: @GaryRussell Kafka is deployed in confluent. There are three partitions in the topic. Two instances of an ECS service are consuming from these partitions. By any chance, can this be causing a problem?

Comment: Right, but you are acking the record before the async processing is complete. That's ok if you don't mind losing records. This has nothing to do with multiple instances, it means a transaction is already in progress but we are trying to start it again for some reason.

Comment: The reason why I suspect multiple instances is, the possibility of having a misconfiguration that causes a transaction to be initiated on a message which is already in transaction.

Comment: No; transactions are local to the current instance.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am sorry for the delayed response. Can you tell me if the following is a possibility?
1. Consumer (having `@Transactional`) starts consuming a message with offset `x` in a transaction; offset is not acknowledged yet; Spring transaction is still incomplete
2. Kafka cluster triggers a consumer rebalance
3. Consumer gets the same partition assigned. Since `x` is still not acknowledged, so the consumer starts consuming again.

Comment: Yes, it's possible if the time to process the records from a `poll()` exceeds `max.poll.interval.ms`. You must ensure the number of records returned by a poll can be processed within that interval, you can reduce `max.poll.records` and/or increase the interval.